# Sliding Tabs in Android

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to have a sliding tab menu that is compatable with 2.x and up. I want this to work with ActionBarSherlock so that it doesn't look different across devices. There seems to be a lot of different ways to have tabs and a pager, but the way that ABS shows "Tabs and Pager" in it's "ABS: Fragments" app running on a 2.3 device defaults to the old style of tabs. There are applications on my 2.3 phone that slide while having tabs and they it looks like ICS. Any ideas on this?

Tabs:
[Picture here](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100)

Comment: something like this? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

try ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Yeah, but I need it to work with tabs. Updated my question to show what kind of tabs I'm talking about.

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad thing to stick to the design defaults of the 2.3 OS for those devices, though I understand we developers want absolute control, and I'm not familiar enough with this...

Do those apps on your phone that work how you want them to have source code available? If you have the APK, you could use APKTool and look at the layout files to see if they're any help.

Comment: I was hoping I could get an answer from someone that has hopefully implemented it before, since it seems to be pretty common.

Comment: Use the tabs built in to the action bar and not a TabWidget like the example you reference does

Comment: Oh! So there are Tabs built into the ActionBar that I can use, and I don't need to use the tab widget. Thanks, I guess I didn't know that there were two ways to display tabs. If I use a tabwidget in 3.0 and higher, I get the new style tabs correct?

Comment: "If I use a tabwidget in 3.0 and higher, I get the new style tabs correct?" -- if by "new style tabs" you mean "tabs in the action bar", then no. `TabHost` and `TabWidget` are for legacy-style tabs. Tabs in the action bar, or tabs associated with a `ViewPager` (via `PagerTabStrip` or Jake's [ViewPagerIndicator project](http://viewpagerindicator.com)) are the "new style tabs".

Comment: Thanks. I guess all I needed was a little clarification.